# Selecting random from two tables in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

When you want to **randomly select** from a table you'll use following code:

```
Select * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT X;
```

But i want to select randomly from **two or more** tables like this:

```
Select * FROM table1, table2, ... ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT X;
```

But above code doesn't work is it possible to do so?:

Comment: Are the two or more tables joined in any way?

Comment: You probably want a union, not a (obsolete syntax) cross join of the two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a cross join of the two tables and then selecting X random rows from that. If you instead want rows from either one of the tables, you want a `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT * FROM table2)
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT ?
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you.